# How does KSPLICE for the desktop interact with the "need to restart to apply changes" dialogue after updates?

Tags: kernel, .desktop

One would expect that it would make those dialogs disappear.  I'm not saying that it doesn't for me, as I haven't installed ksplice.  I am saying I'ld like to know whether it works to eliminate those dialogs for both desktop and desktop with kernel edgers PPAs.

Comment: There isnt an update check happening for these PPAs or the code is telling it to displayupdatemessage=always.